# Draw a line on top of a field

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]
I'm struggling with a thing that would seen very simple.

I have a text field with some color set and a line. I would like the line to be over the textbox. But it is behind and I can't find any way to change it. In every application there is something like "bring to front" "bring to back" but not here. No transparency option too.

Comment: Aside: The official product name should be changed to "Crustal Reports".

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same problem. 
In order to solve this, I've set a **box** object as background.
Then it's possible to insert text or line objects over the **box** by disabling background checkbox on Format Object.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You normally can't control the line z-order, but you can right-click the text object and select `Move -> To Back`.  Works in VS 2005 or newer.